# Update Available message appears automatically - android

Tags: java, android

May I ask you a question?

I built an android application but it's not on google play store. I would like to add an update alert message there so i try WVersionManager - https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WVersionManager. It clearly run in test but nothing happened after clicking "Update Now" button.

The main problem is where can i add my application apk link - I uploaded update_content_json_format.txt and it worked well. That text file is only for the update information -

```
{"version_code":2,"content":"Version 2.0
<p>New features:</p>
<li>Added feature A</li>
<li>Added feature B</li>
<li>Added feature C</li>
<li>Added feature D</li>
<li>Added feature E</li>
<li>Added feature F</li>
<li>Added feature G</li>"}
```

please point me where can i add my update application apk link which is not from playstore.

-- or --

According to the idea, I would like to know how to show update available dialog box automatically whenever I open the application.

Thank you very much!

With Regards,

Answer (score 0):

wow .. I am okay with the external download link!

I changed a little bit on original (some of codes are not used but i don't know to delete yet)

```
package com.winsontan520.wversionmanager.sample;

import com.winsontan520.wversionmanager.sample.R;
import com.winsontan520.wversionmanager.library.WVersionManager;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class CheckVersionActivity extends Activity {

    // this is just a sample url to retrieve update content, the return content must follow the json format as stated in readme.md
    public final static String URL_VERSION_2 = "http://......."; // this link is refer to a static text file hosted using dropbox
    public final static String URL_VERSION_3 = "http://........";

    private EditText versionContentUrl;
    private EditText updateNowLabel;
    private EditText remindMeLaterLabel;
    private EditText ignoreThisVersionLabel;
    private EditText reminderTimer;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.check_version);

        versionContentUrl = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.versionContentUrl);
        updateNowLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.updateNowLabel);
        remindMeLaterLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.remindMeLaterLabel);
        ignoreThisVersionLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ignoreThisVersionLabel);
        reminderTimer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.reminderTimer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void onClickHandler(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.use_version_2_button:
            versionContentUrl.setText(URL_VERSION_2);
            break;
        case R.id.use_version_3_button:
            versionContentUrl.setText(URL_VERSION_3);
            break;
        case R.id.check_version_button:
            checkVersion();
            break;
        }
    }

    private void checkVersion() {
        WVersionManager versionManager = new WVersionManager(this);

        versionManager.setVersionContentUrl(versionContentUrl.getText().toString());
        versionManager.setUpdateNowLabel(updateNowLabel.getText().toString());
        versionManager.setRemindMeLaterLabel(remindMeLaterLabel.getText().toString());
        versionManager.setIgnoreThisVersionLabel(ignoreThisVersionLabel.getText().toString());
        versionManager.setReminderTimer(Integer.valueOf(reminderTimer.getText().toString()));

        versionManager.checkVersion();

        versionManager.setUpdateNowLabel("Update Now!");
        versionManager.setRemindMeLaterLabel("Not Yet");
        versionManager.setIgnoreThisVersionLabel("Remind me soon");
        versionManager.setUpdateUrl("http://......../uploads/ExampleListActivity.apk"); // this is the link will execute when update now clicked. default will go to google play based on your package name.
        versionManager.setReminderTimer(10);
    }

}
```

but i still want to know to show update available dialog box automatically whenever I enter the application without clicking "check for update" button.

With Regards,